# Count number of spaces and words in an integer

Tags: c, count

I'm trying to write a C program that counts the number of words and spaces in a given string. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, spaces;
  char a[30];
  printf("enter the string");
  scanf("%s", a);
  for(i=0 ; a[0]!="\0" ; i++
    {
      if (a[i]=' ')
        {
          spaces++;
        }
    }
  printf("Number of spaces is %d", spaces);
  printf("Number of words is %d", spaces + 1);
}
```

It gives me a weird error at 9:19. Help would be much appreciated.

Updated:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
   int i,spaces;
   char a[100];
   printf("enter the string\n");
   scanf("%s",a);
   for(i=0 ; a[i]!='\0' ; i++)
     {
       if (a[i]==' ')
     {
     spaces++;
     }
     }
   printf("the no. of spaces in the string is %d\n",spaces);
   printf("the no. of words in the string is %d\n",spaces+1);
 }
```

Now doesn't metter what string I input, it'll say there's 0 spaces and 1 word. Why is this?

Comment: Can you tell us what the "weird error" is? I mean, I have a pretty good guess, but we ask this of everyone.

Comment: ISO c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.

Comment: So you started off by saying you're writing C, but you are compiling into C++ I see...

Comment: Replace `a[0]!="\0"` with `a[0]!='\0'`. But there are other errors, such as `a[i]=' '` ...

Comment: Does this even compile? Looks like you are missing the closing brace for the for loop.

Comment: Updated code and error in OP message. Please check it out.

Comment: scanf reads input delimited by string.  your program will always have 1 word and 0 spaces.  use fgets() instead

Comment: @drch I've tried replacing scanf with fgets and it gives me the following error: too few arguements to function 'char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)

Comment: @kiasy What is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first think, you forgot the for closing parenthese. And the condition expression you must use `'\0'` instead of `"\0"`. Also you need to check `a[i]` not `a[0]`.

```
 for(i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
 {
     if (a[i] == ' ')
     {
          spaces++;
     }
  }
```

Note that you should initialize `spaces` to `0` before using it.

```
spaces = 0;
```

**Update:**

Another thing, to input a full string with spaces use `fgets()` instead of `scanf`:

```
fgets(a, 100, stdin);
```

The first argument is your string, the second is the maximum number of characters to input and the third is the stream from where you will get the input: `stdin` in your case wich is the standard input stream.

Live exemple: https://eval.in/101504

Comment: Your condition `a[i]! = '\0'` is not good, need to remove the space in the middle.

Comment: @AntonH Tanks. Just a typo!

Comment: Thought so, just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Updated code and error in OP message. Please check it out.

Comment: You could at least explain why he has to put in 100 for the maxsize.

Comment: I've kept the printf statement and added fgets(a,30,stdin) and now when I run the program it just doesn't do anything @rullof

Comment: @rullof please excuse my stupidity today. Your answer is 100%. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In C, a `char[]` literal is written with double quotes (`"`), and a `char` literal is written with single quotes (`'`). Change `"\0"` to `'\0'`. This is the source of your "weird error."

The bracket syntax is syntactic sugar for dereferencing an offset pointer to a contiguous block of memory, based on what you declared it would contain. Maybe a crude diagram could help? This is a depiction of a `char[5]`. It's a pointer block of memory that can hold 5 `char`s and a null terminator.

```
['h']['e']['l']['l']['o']['\0']
  ^
  a // you called your char[] a, so I did too
```

A `char*` is a pointer to a `char`. So you could also call `a` a `char*`. Say you wanted to access the first `'l'` in the `char[]`... well, you'd have to point to the address exactly `2*sizeof(char)` ahead. `a[2]` is the same thing as `*(a+(2*sizeof(char)))`.

So when you dereferenced your `char*` you got a `char`, obviously. But `"\0"` is a `char[]` literal (i.e. a string) and you can't compare the two.

*Other problems:* you should close the parentheses on your `for` loop, and make your comparison `a[i]!='\0'` (that way you are checking each `char` as you iterate through the `char[]`. I think you also meant to check `if(a[i]==' ')`. Otherwise you will be clearing out your string with spaces :)

A little tip for going forward: if you are comparing a variable to a literal, put the literal first so you're less likely to make typos like that. e.g. `' '==a[i]`. If you used `=` instead you would get an error (because you'd be trying to assign something to a literal).

**Edit**: since you updated your code, I'd like to point out that you should probably initialize `spaces` to be `0`.

Now I won't take credit for this, but in case someone in the future is reading, [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) is what you're looking to use instead of [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). Thanks to drch for pointing this out.

Comment: Updated code and error in OP message. Please check it out.

Comment: Hey, I've initialized 'int spaces = 0;' and and 'int i;'. Still shows the the same thing. 0 spaces, 1 word :( Any suggestions ? I've upvoted your answer BTW.

Comment: Ah a user named drch pointed out the answer in a comment. (I always forget the `stdio` functions and what they do.)

Comment: I've replied to him.. Please check it out.

Comment: So, at this point, it'd be up to you to read the docs... I've got to leave something up to you to figure out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're always comparing a[0] to '\0' so your loop continues endlessly, compare it to a[i].
One more thing is that "\0" is a string (char*), you need to compare it to '\0' which is a char.

Comment: Updated code and error in OP message. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting 0 and 1 is because of the way you're using scanf.  Using scanf with %s just reads the first string that does not include white space.  So if you typed

"The fox jumped over the moon"

The output will be 0 spaces and 1 word.  This is because scanf(%s, a) will just put "The" into a and will ignore the rest of the string.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

You can use scanf("[^\r\n]", a).  I believe that should get you what you want (or close to it anyway).